# Считывание данных Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net

Почему выдает программа не верный формат ввода?

```
    private static IPAddress remoteIPAddress;
    private static int remotePort;
    private static int localPort;
    private static string User_name;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                User_name = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
                localPort = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
                remotePort = Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text);
                remoteIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                Thread tRec = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receiver));
                tRec.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    Send(textBox5.Text);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Возникло исключение: " + ex.ToString() + "\n  " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вводил такие данные 
127.0.0.1  localPort
904 remotePort

**СТРОКА 74**  `localPort = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);`

Comment: Покажите: 1) на какой строке возникло исключение; 2) полный тип исключения и сообщение об ошибке; 3) какое значение было введено в соответствующий `textBox`

Comment: ` localPort = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
                remotePort = Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text);
                remoteIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(textBox4.Text);`

Comment: Внесите всю нужную информацию в вопрос с помощью кнопки «править».

Comment: Все.@defaultlocale

Comment: Не все. 1) Вставьте сообщение текстом, а не картинкой 2) Укажите какая строка № 74 3) Покажите какое значение введено в `textBox`

Comment: @defaultlocale ну вот все

Comment: Оно не копируется с него( по этому остается скрин)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76092/discussion-between-default-locale-and-ilya-burmaka).

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka весь текст message board, включая title, можно скопировать просто нажав ctrl+c, без выделения.

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka и текстбоксы стоит называть полноценными именами, а не textBox1/2/3/4 - меньше шансов будет, что вы перепутаете, и возьмете текст не из того текстбокса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто, первое и самое главное, что вам нужно - это хранить порты в строковом типе.

То что вы пытаетесь сделать сейчас: взять число `127001`, именно такое, потому что С# воспринимает точку как удобный пользователю визуальный разделитель, это удобно к примеру для работы с большими числами `int a = 1.000.000;`, и пихаете это число в `Int16`, диапазон которого `Int16 (-32,768 to +32,767)`.

То есть, вы пытаетесь загнать в `Int16` число, превышающие максимальный размер диапазона, отсюда компилятор и выдает ошибку.

Если же все таки, по каким-то причинам, вы собираетесь хранить `localPort` в `int`, то используйте `Convert.ToInt32();`